# How to instantiate a model from an Ecore meta-model in the same workspace and not in a runtime Eclipse environment?

Tags: eclipse-emf, ecore

I have a meta-model constructed using Ecore and now I want to instantiate it in same workspace or another workspace, but not in a runtime Eclipse environment.

Most of the example I saw were using runtime Eclipse.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: I don't really understand what you want to do. You can instantiate Java objects that represents EMF model elements with the model package factory (`SomeFactory.eINSTANCE.createXXX`). This works also without a Eclipse runtime.

Comment: EMF works fine without an Eclipse runtime. The only thing you have to do is to put the right jars on your classpath. See [this FAQ entry](https://wiki.eclipse.org/EMF/FAQ#I_want_to_use_EMF.2C_SDO.2C_or_XSD_in_my_standalone_project.2C_or_include_only_a_working_subset_of_the_code._What_libraries_.28jar_files.29_do_I_need_in_my_CLASSPATH.3F) for information about this.

Answer (score 1):

If you open your metamodel using the arborescent editor, right click on one of your (concrete) EClass, there should be an entry "Create Dynamic Instance...".

Another way is you can generate Java code from your metamodel and programmatically use the generated classes to create your model "by hand". See EMF tutorials like http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseEMF/article.html on how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

From the explorer view , you click right on the object that you wanna as a root for your model then click on`Create Dynamic Instance`